# Capacity of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

What is the maximum capacity of a `textarea`  that it can accept some text.The html page is working fine when the text limits to about 130-140 words.But when the text exceeds that limit it doesn't do anything(just hangs). This text is passed through `javascript` for some manipulations and displayed in another `textarea`. If there is a limit how to make it accept large amount of text?

**UPDATE :**

I get the following error when I check the error log

```
request failed: URI too long (longer than 8190)
```

I am using the following line to pass the text through `javascript`

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","./analyze.pl?unk="+str ,true);
```

Comment: Example code could help finding cause of hang.

Comment: posted error @Anthony

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the `<textarea>`. The problem is that you are creating a URL that is [too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers).

Submit the data using a `POST`, not a `GET` and the problem will go away.

As a general rule: if you have occasion to worry about URL length, you are probably passing too much data via query string parameters. From a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) standpoint, consider that a GET is used to retrieve a resource. A GET should not be used to submit data that will create/update a resource (such as one might do when entering data into a `<textarea>`).

Comment: Are you POSTing *and* removing the large parameter(s) from the URL?

Comment: I didn't understand what are you asking

Answer (score 0):

I use a `maxlength` of **8000** on one of my sites and it didn't have any problems. Your javascript must be the cause of the problem (guessing **infinite/long loops**) OR it must be the **browser** your testing on OR your **computer**.

It would be best if you show your javascript code.

Comment: thats the error but we still need the code that caused the problem. if you cant show more info then no one can help you. but a quick google search https://www.google.com/search?q=request+failed%3A+URI+too+long&rlz=1C1ASUC_enPH552PH552&oq=request+failed%3A+URI+too+long&aqs=chrome..69i57.593j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&q=request+failed%3A+URI+too+long will show related concerns of the error. you might find something useful.